# Modal Notification Appear On Form Send, Foundation/Abide.js

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, zurb-foundation

[I'm doing something very similar to this site here](http://avalontx.com/). When you send the form that is in in the footer, a modal window appears upon successful sending that thanks the user for submitting a form. I've built a site in Foundation and am validating the fields using Abide.js.

Everything was working this morning until I tried using different AJAX/jQuery methods to have a message appear on the same page where the form is instead of the modal. Now that I'm trying to do the modal, my form isn't working at all.

Here's my form's HTML:

```
<form id="form-contact" name="form-contact" action="include/contact-form-send.php" method="post" data-abide>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <input id="contact-name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Full Name" pattern="alpha" required />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <input id="contact-email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email Address" pattern="email" required />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-12 columns">
        <input id="contact-phone" name="phone" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" pattern="number" required />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-6 medium-6 small-12 columns" id="form-left">
        <input id="contact-security" name="security" type="text" placeholder="10 - 3 =" pattern="[7]" required />
    </div>
    <div class="large-6 medium-6 small-12 columns" id="form-right">
    <input type="submit" value="submit" class="button green-button" id="form-send" />
    </div>
</div>
```

PHP:

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];

$to = "example@email.com";
$subj = "The Rivers Quick Contact Request";
$mess = "The following person has filled out the quick contact form on The Rivers    website:

Name: $name
Email: $email
Phone: $phone
";

$headers = "From: info@therivers.com" . "\r\n" .
"CC:example@email.com";
$mailsend = mail($to,$subj,$mess,$headers);
```

And ideally the line of JS that would help the modal appear when the form is sent, [using a function as defined by Foundation here.](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/abide.html)

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $('#form-contact').on('valid.fndtn.abide', function() {
     $('.modal').css({'opacity':'1'});
   });
});
```

It's my understanding that the Abide.js should be taking care of all the validation, and then the PHP file will send the form to the specified email. I'm having a hard time figuring out where to go from here now that I've broken it.

Comment: If someone has a better method of calling in the modal, that would be awesome too. I realize that just setting the opacity to 1 with it being a fixed element makes it impossible to get to any of the links in the middle of the page.

Comment: You could just set the visibility with css and it shouldn't hinder other elements `$('.modal').hide()` or `.show()`

Answer (score 1):

I think we're missing too much code to be of much help :/

When I go to the provided link, your php error is at line 19, but there aren't 19 lines of php provided.

Have you syntax checked your php?  If not, [here's a php syntax checker](http://phpcodechecker.com/).

Concerning calling the modal, have you tried foundation's reveal modal plugin?  [Check it out if you haven't](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/reveal.html).

Great looking site btw!